# Can we have a "duplicate answer" reminder?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-answers

I've noticed some new users (and unfortunately some less than new users) have a tendency to copy-paste answers across multiple questions.

What would be *really* nice is if at *X* identical answers, the user was informed via a popup or banner that "You've posted X identical answers - if the questions are identical, you may wish to flag or vote to close as duplicate".

Since mods already get flags for duplicates - there's definitely some logic for detecting them, but it would mean we just deal with the ones who *don't get it* rather than the ones who know.

And yeah, this is vaguely an attempt to automate mods out of a job ;).

Comment: I think X >= 2, where x is an integer, would be appropriate i.e. try to catch it as close to the outset of that answering pattern as possible.

Comment: @PolyGeo You mean x >= 2, where x is an integer

Comment: X >1? I suppose. X seems to be something like 2-3 for the mod flags.

Comment: Note that if you notify the user, rather than just silently notifying a mod, and they *do* realize they're doing something wrong, they'll now have a good signal for when they've made enough trivial changes to the post to not notify a mod, allowing it to better evade detection.  Not sure if that's enough to not do this, but still something to be wary of.

Comment: That's kind of at least part of the point

Answer (score 2):

This would be a nice addition.

Users are supposed to flag/close questions as duplicates and not "borrow" answers to do their own answer (unless it's to help but that's a different thing). So, duplicating answers would kinda be on the same line as duplicate answers. Thus not only would they get a warning like this:

> You have posted 2 or more answers that are very similar or identical. If you find that the question has a duplicate, please flag/close the question as a duplicate rather than answering the question.

the warning might count slightly against them towards the answer ban (there is one right?) Of course, don't count the first warning. The OP of the answer might not even be aware he posted those very similar answers before in the first place.

So, yes, add some type of message like the above to warn the user. After a few times, a moderator may be needed to be involved (again) and a very thorough discussion/message will probably be needed though this might get complicated...

Comment: The mechanism for getting a moderator involved is already there. I'd like this deal with those who don't know better mainly